# Why am I seeing a 'did not find expected node content' when implementing this condition within Cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I want to retrieve different resourceRecords, depending on whether my condition is true, else changing the string if the name is something else. Here is my example:

```
myDNSresource:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
    Condition: devEnv
    Properties:
      HostedZoneName: {"Fn::ImportValue": !Sub "${stackName}-${AWS::Region}-dnsZone"}
      Name: !Join [".", [!Ref hostname, {"Fn::ImportValue": !Sub "${stackname}-${AWS::Region}-dnsZone"}]]
      Type: CNAME
      TTL: 130
      ResourceRecords:
        - !If [conditionIsTrue, !Join [".", [{"Fn::ImportValue": !Sub "${accountStackName}-${AWS::Region}-dnsZone"}]],
            - !Join
            - ""
            - - !GetAtt
              - domainName
              - regionalValue
              - "." 
        ]
```

I have run cfn-lint and I am seeing an error regarding `did not find expected node content` just before the `!Join` command, directly after my `!If` statement. I am following the condition formula of ->

```
!If [condition_name, value_if_true, value_if_false]
```

Thanks

Comment: So what's the `value_if_false` here? You have a syntax error at least - there are 3 opening brackets and only 2 closing ones.

Comment: The value of if false is everything after the second -Join statement. The closing bracket is the very last line of code

Comment: Alright, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

In YAML, flow-style nodes (i.e. `[…]`, `{…}`) cannot contain block-style nodes (i.e. everything that is structured with indentation). Also, you have multiple structures that do not make sense, e.g.

```yaml
- !Join
- ""
```

Here, the first item is tagged with `!Join` but empty, so nothing will be joined. Same goes for

```yaml
- !GetAtt
- domainName
```

A rewrite which seems to make sense would be

```yaml
- !If
  - conditionIsTrue
  - !Join [".", ["Fn::ImportValue": !Sub "${accountStackName}-${AWS::Region}-dnsZone"]]
  - !Join
    - ""
    - !GetAtt
      - domainName
      - regionalValue
      - "."
```

As you can see, I dropped the inner `{…}` because YAML supports `[a: b]` as shorthand notation for `[{a: b}]`.

If you want to use flow-style nodes, you need to make all contained nodes flow-style:

```yaml
- !If [
    conditionIsTrue, 
    !Join [
      ".",
      ["Fn::ImportValue": !Sub "${accountStackName}-${AWS::Region}-dnsZone"]
    ],
    !Join ["", !GetAtt [domainName, regionalValue, "."]]
  ]
```

Comment: Thank you, however after following your example I am still seeing the same issue. Also, you mention that -GetAtt -domainName will not do anything however it's obtaitning the value of the domainName and using it as the name of the resource record. You need to specify a delimiter with the Join statement so that's why "" is directly after it.

Comment: @i'i'i'i'i'i'i'i'i'i You misunderstood my point. For `!GetAttr` to do something it must be applied to the node that contains the value name. In your code, `!GetAttr` is applied to an empty node which is part of a sequence, and the next item in the sequence is `domainName` – which is not seen by `!GetAttr`. Compare that to my suggestion where `!GetAttr` is applied to the whole sequence containing `domainName` etc. btw, [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getatt.html) suggest you may need to do `!GetAttr domainName.regionalValue`